# python code for improved euler's method using predictor-corrector method

Tags: python

I am attempting to learn Python and thought it would be interesting to look back at some old Math stuff and see if I could write a program using numerical methods to solve ODEs.  I was able to come up with a program for Euler's method without too much trouble, but now I am trying to alter it so that it uses the predictor corrector method and can't seem to get it right.

Euler's Method:

```
def f(x,y):
  return (0.2*x*y)

def eulers(x,y,h,xfinal):
  print(y)
  iters = int((xfinal-x)/h)
  for i in range(1,iters+1):
    y = y + h*(f(x,y))
    print(y)

print(eulers(1,1,0.05,1.5))
```

Improved Euler's Method (what I've attempted so far):

```
def f(x,y):
  return (0.2*x*y)

y = float(input('enter initial y value:'))
x = float(input('enter initial x value:'))
h = float(input('enter step size:'))
xfinal = float(input('enter final x value to be  approximated:'))
iters = int((xfinal - x)/(h))

xA = np.zeros(iters+1)
xA[0] = x
for i in range(iters):
  xA[i+1] = xA[i] + h
print(xA)

yA = np.zeros(iters+1)
yA[0] = y

for i in range(0,iters):
  f1 = yA[i] + h*(f(xA[i],yA[i]))
  yA[i+1] = yA[i] + h*( (f(xA[i],yA[i]) + f(xA[i+1],f1) )/ 2 )

print()
newlist = list()
for i in yA:
  newlist.append(i)
for i in newlist:
  print(i)
```

The textbook I'm using states that the improved method uses the formula Yn+1 = Yn + h*(f(Xn,Yn)+f(Xn+1,^Yn+1^))/2, where ^Yn+1^  is the formula used in the original Euler's method(Yn+1 = Yn + h*f(Xn,Yn).  Since there are two computations necessary for each iteration of the predictor-corrector method, I tried both of the following:

```
for i in range(0,iters):
  f1 = yA[i] + h*(f(xA[i],yA[i]))
  yA[i+1] = yA[i] + h*( (f(xA[i],yA[i]) + f(xA[i+1],f1) )/ 2 )
```

AND

```
for i in range(0,iters):
  yA[i+1] = yA[i] + h*(f(xA[i],yA[i]))
  yA[i+1] = yA[i] + h*( (f(xA[i],yA[i]) + f(xA[i+1],yA[i+1]) )/ 2 )
```

but neither seems to work.  I end up getting the same numbers as if I were to run the program using the original Euler's method (as if I just ran:

```
for i in range(0,iters):
  yA[i+1] = yA[i] + h*(f(xA[i],yA[i]))
```

which gives less accurate approximations.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Minor note: `range(0,iters)` is just `range(iters)`. Also, you seem to be copying `yA` into a list at the end, but doing that very inefficiently. You can call `newlist = yA.tolist()` (because it's a numpy array). But you can just print the array too: `print(yA)`.

Comment: As for your actual question: forget efficiency for a moment and try to compute both "`Y hat`" and `Y` in parallel; one with the original Euler, the other based on this other one, exactly according to the definition. Do you still get the same result? The problem might be that you keep computing the "uncorrected" Y hat from the previous _corrected_ value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but I computed Y (or Yhat in this case) using the original Euler's method (with the code for the improved method), and it gave me the correct approximations.  I tried defining 'yhat' as 'f1' for the improved method thinking that using 'yA[I+1]' for both lines of the for loop was the problem, but that change didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that the loop works fine.  I was looking at the functions at the beginning of the program and not paying attention to some minor details in the problems I'm using for practice.  Thank you for your help though.